# Изменение ConnectionString в DataSet VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, visual-basic

Добрый день. Не получается изменить строку подключения для DataSet1.
У меня строка формируется с использованием пользовательского IP-адреса. База данных MS SQL.

```
connectionString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=" & ipAddress & ";Password=17561791;User ID=sa;Initial Catalog=TngCt"
```

Пытался изменить таким способом:

```
My.Settings.Item("ConnectionString") = connectionString
```

Но базу все равно открывает которая была изначально задана при добавлении DataSet.
В App.config у меня строка подключения отсутствует. По требованиям, ее там быть не должно. Как можно еще изменить строку подключения для DataSet? Спасибо

Проблема решена простым куском кода:

```
Dim conn As New OleDbConnection(connectionString)
conn.Open()        
Dim da As New OleDbDataAdapter(query, conn)
da.Fill(ds)
conn.Close()
```

Всем спасибо!)

Comment: [sql connection using vb.net](https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/170218/sql-connection-using-vb-net)

Comment: [Класс SqlConnection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2)

Answer (score 0):

Создание с помощью класса [SqlConnection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2):

```
Public Sub CreateCommand(ByVal queryString As String, _
  ByVal connectionString As String)
    Using connection As New SqlConnection(connectionString)
        Dim command As New SqlCommand(queryString, connection)
        command.Connection.Open()
        command.ExecuteNonQuery()
    End Using
End Sub
```

Создание с помощью класса [OleDbConnection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.data.oledb.oledbconnection(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
Public Sub InsertRow(ByVal connectionString As String, _
    ByVal insertSQL As String)

    Using connection As New OleDbConnection(connectionString)
        ' The insertSQL string contains a SQL statement that
        ' inserts a new row in the source table.
        Dim command As New OleDbCommand(insertSQL)

        ' Set the Connection to the new OleDbConnection.
        command.Connection = connection

        ' Open the connection and execute the insert command.
        Try
            connection.Open()
            command.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Catch ex As Exception
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message)
        End Try
        ' The connection is automatically closed when the
        ' code exits the Using block.
    End Using
End Sub
```

Comment: в отладчике дальше строчки  Using connection As New SqlConnection(connectionString) не идет. Сразу запускается приложение. Использую OLE DB

Comment: [OleDbConnectionStringBuilder Class](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.data.oledb.oledbconnectionstringbuilder?view=netframework-4.7.1)